# An unexpected issue with join

Tags: bash, join

I have two files, both contain similar contents and are sorted with `awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -n"}'`

`file1.tmp`:

```
contigID:totalAvgDepth
2011_07_08_contig_100000:3.17112
2011_07_08_contig_100001:1.81928
2011_07_08_contig_100002:2.96875
2011_07_08_contig_100003:2.37912
```

and  `file2.tmp`:

```
contigID:GCContent
2011_07_08_contig_100000:59.6439169139466
2011_07_08_contig_100001:36.0759493670886
2011_07_08_contig_100002:67.6470588235294
2011_07_08_contig_100003:65.0602409638554
2011_07_08_contig_100004:64.7409172126266
```

I use `join -t':' file1.tmp file2.tmp > merged.txt` and at the end I get this error:

```
join: file2.tmp:8: is not sorted: 2011_07_08_contig_10000:60.0273317389819
join: file1.tmp:16: is not sorted: 2011_07_08_contig_10001:3.16236
```

When I check manually, the first `2011_07_08_contig_10000` is present in both `file1.tmp` and `file2.tmp` but not present in `merged.txt`. However, `2011_07_08_contig_10001:` is present everywhere.

So the questions I am asking are:

1. Which step is working in the wrong way?
2. How can I fix it?
3. When I check `wc -l file1.tmp file2.tmp merged.txt`, I get a weird output

```
394278 file1.tmp
394278 file2.tmp
359112 merged.txt
```

as I expect `merged.txt` to be identical to `file1,2` in terms of lines. How to 'align' them properly?

There's obviously something wrong, any ideas? Probably there's a better way?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem using the lines that you have shared here? Can you edit to make a [mcve] with the full series of commands? It sounds like maybe your input is missing some lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting the files on the column you use for joining:

```
join -t: <(sort -t: -k1,1 file1.tmp) <(sort -t: -k1,1 file2.tmp) > merged.txt
```

Or use the similar incantation when sorting the output of awk.